# appropriate sarcastic "almost died"

Tags: colloquial-language

Would "死んでいたそう(ね)" be an appropriate translation for "looks like you almost died (there)"?

Imagine you throw your scarf around your neck and almost hit a person. Except a scarf hardly hurts and actually it was so far away it could have never hit the person.
Yet the person looks at you as if you almost killed her/him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the most common and natural-sounding phrases for that type of situations would be:

> 「死ぬところだったね。」
>
> 「死んじゃうところだったね。」
>
> 「死ぬかと思ったでしょう？」

I would personally recommend the second one above.

「"死んでいたそう(ね)"」 would not work because it expresses hearsay meaning:

"I hear (someone) was already dead (then)."

Comment: I wonder if the OP was thinking of 連用形 + **そう**になる. Could that construction be used naturally here?

Comment: If it were 死にそうになった, it would be very natural.

Answer (score 0):

I think these might sound funny if said quickly / abruptly

> なくならないようにお願い。
>   死亡しそうだと思った。気を付けてね。
>   くたばちゃたっら、いけないなのでご注意ね。

Comment: 「死亡したそうだと思った」 - do you mean 「死亡しそうだと思った」?

Comment: `くたばちゃったら` `いけないなので` -- Can you double check you spelled them correctly.

Comment: `くたばちゃたっら` <- I think you meant to type「くたば**っ**ちゃ**っ**たら」（日本語に「(た)っら」っていうのはないです）「いけないので」（not ない+な+ので but ない+ので）